# Graphically display $a^3+b^3+c^3 = d^3$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

As a kind of 'addition' to Fermats Last Theorem, a friend of mine has come up with a different idea.
Let $$a^3+b^3+c^3 = d^3$$
with $(a,b,c,d): a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{N}$.

We were discussing Pythagoras: how you could constuct a triangle from two sides ($a$, $b$) of two squares ($a^2$, $b^2$) (at a right angle), which results in the third side of the triangle, which is also the side of the third square ($c^2$).

How could we do that with a dimension higher, if we say that $a$, $b$ and $c$ are sides of cubes, and we position the cubes in a 3D (x, y, z) coordinate system. How will the fourth cube (with side $d$) come from the three cubes?

We know that the set $a = 3$, $b = 4$, $c = 5$ and $d = 6$ work out, and we've tried putting all of the sides on an axis each, and calculating the area of the triangle the three points make. This made sense to us: two sides of two squares make a line, so three sides of three cubes, should make an area. The area of the triangle was a dead end (as far as we could find, the area ($\frac{\sqrt{769}}{2}$)has nothing to do with the number 6), and we couldn't think of anything more.

The questions:

- Is there any way to position the three cubes, that they make sense in
  the same way the squares in a Pythagoras triangle make sense?
- How does the fourth cube come from the three cubes, just like in a Pythagoras triangle.

Comment: I think you mean "two sides of a squares" -> "two sides of two squares" and "How does the third cube" -> "How does the fourth cube"?

Comment: Thanks. I had a hard time formulating the question.

Answer (score 2):

It's a nice idea. I don't know of any way to make it work with the cubes, but you might like this interpretation of the triangle whose area you calculated. That area is (with $\vec a,\vec b,\vec c$ the vectors corresponding to the three sides)

$$\frac12\left|\left(\vec a-\vec b\right)\times\left(\vec b - \vec c\right)\right|\;,$$

so its square comes out as

$$\left(\frac12\vec a\times \vec b\right)^2+\left(\frac12\vec b\times \vec c\right)^2+\left(\frac12\vec c\times \vec a\right)^2\;,$$

which is the sum of the squares of the areas of the three other triangles formed by the three sides.

(I found this idea [here](http://www.odeion.org/pythagoras/pythag3d.html), but the proofs there are unnecessarily complicated.)

This generalizes to higher dimensions, with the cross product replaced by the exterior product.